# Lost connection to MySQL server, system error: 111

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to connect to my databases, I get this error:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error:111
```

Here is my PHP code (it's just a test):

```
<?php
@session_start(); 
include(".conf.php");
print_r($conf);
$con = mysql_connect($conf['db_hostname'], $conf['db_username'], $conf['db_password']) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("aTableName", $con);
$prof = '000';
//$prof = $_GET['profile'];
$prof = addslashes(htmlentities($prof));
$result = "SELECT * FROM aTableName WHERE id = '$prof'";
$q = mysql_query($result, $con);
$qarr = mysql_fetch_array($q);
print_r($qarr); 
?>
```

*Any* help would be appreciated. I can't figure it out and it's really bugging me. Thank you!

EDIT: I am hosting on GoDaddy, hosting and databases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your host is wrong, your port is wrong, a firewall blocked the connection, or the SQL server is not running. 111 is "connection refused". You can troubleshoot by trying to `telnet` to the SQL server's host and port. If that works, your code gets the host or port wrong.

If that doesn't work, check on the SQL server itself. If it works there, the problem is the network. If it doesn't work there, the SQL server is not running.

Comment: The server works because I can connect to it using PHPMyAdmin. I am using a Mac  so I'm pretty sure I can't telnet.

Comment: By "the server", I mean the SQL server (not the web server). And I mean you should try to `telnet` to the SQL server's host and SQL port from the server machine itself. (Doesn't matter if they're the same physical machine or not, the test process is the same.)

Comment: So either the SQL server isn't running or the host/port information you are using to reach it isn't correct.

Answer (score 3):

Check my.cnf file. It probably allows localhost to connect but your conf.php surely tries to connect to your IP or 127.0.0.1. Try with localhost and, if it works and you want it to behave in a different way, edit your my.cnf file in the bind-address directive (changing it to your IP or to 127.0.0.1, perhaps, or commenting the line so no binding is performed).

Anyway, when you connect to mysql with "localhost", it uses a socket instead of a TCP conn, hence it probably fails with that,

Comment: Gives me this error: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/75/8274475/html/Tests/profile.php on line 7
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: I suppose this is the test with localhost ¿Did you restart the mysql service? And... if it doesn't work even with restarting, check this thread with some config on the DB. http://serverfault.com/questions/128564/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-postfix

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I was trying to access the mysql DB on the server 192.168.0.4 from a client machine 192.168.0.47. When I went into /etc/mysql/my.cnf an changed the bind-address = 192.168.0.4 (and commented out 127.0.0.1), and rebooted the machine, the error message went away.

Comment: I tried this and It stopped the whole application. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have datadir=/media/sdc1/mysql and the disk was not mounted.
i Remount and restart mysql

Answer (score 0):

In my case disk is full. You have to remove any not necessary files.

If you removed then you have to restart mysqld.

For example: `sudo service mysqld restart`